# Not working formula in Query Builder (Filter)

Tags: qgis, query, filter, formula

I have been trying to filter a big dataset based on multiple values. The idea is to extend the formula as put in the image below. But even the first part doesn't work.

When I do: `"kadastraleGemeenteWaarde" IN 'Ridderkerk'` I get all results. If I do `"kadastraleGemeenteWaarde" = 'Ridderkerk'` I get no results.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
("kadastraleGemeenteWaarde" LIKE 'Ridderkerk') AND ("sectie" LIKE 'E')
```

The brackets are important for correct chaining of expressions. The change to `LIKE` is probably unnecessary, but to me it feels "cleaner", since I use `IN` only if I have a real list.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. 

Unfortunately, I did not get any results with the formula.and when I changed LIKE to IN I get all rows.

Comment: Can you provide a data sample? If not, you have to try on your own, if the parts of the expression are working when used alone.

Comment: Yeah sure that would be of great help. It's a public wfs source. 

https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/kadastralekaart/wfs/v4_0?version=2.0

If you prefer I can share it in another format.

Comment: Yeah, and which of the possible layers are you working with? And are you working directly on the WFS, or did you download the data first?

Comment: I worked with the wfs in the layer Cadastral Parcel.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, if you browse the data (Open Attribute Table) then you can hit the 'Filter' button at the top. This gives you a GUI filter window.
The best thing about this, is that it will give you the Expression at the bottom of that GUI.
In your instance, I used the GUI to enter Ridderkerk as a 'Contains' filter. then ran the filter. It returned the resultant features.
Better yet, it showed me the expression to use.

```
("kadastraleGemeenteWaarde" ILIKE '%Ridderkerk%')
```

This GUI should help you build your expression correctly.